# Why is this python script throwing a "FileNotFoundError" when the file actually does exist?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i have a simple scraping script that essentially scrapes a list of book/markdown titles from a github repo and then creates respective directories for each of the book titles after which it scrapes chapter titles and links to the chapter markdown files for each of those books. But i run into a "FileNotFoundError" after the script 'touches' the first chapter title. I see the first file has been created but when the script calls open() function on the chapter title, it throws an error saying no such file or directory found. I made sure the script is working in the correct directory and is being passed the relative path to the file and that the file permissions are appropriate. I am running this script in a python virtual environment so maybe this is some undefined behavior. The exception is thrown at line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import subprocess
import os

r = requests.get('https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/README.md')

page = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
article_container = page.find('article', class_="markdown-body")
unordered_list = article_container.find('ul')
lists = unordered_list.find_all('li')

dict_of_books = {}


for li_element in lists:
    rel_path = li_element.find('a').get('href') 
    abs_path = 'https://github.com' + rel_path
    title = li_element.find('a').get_text().strip('\"')
    dict_of_books[title] = abs_path

for k,v in dict_of_books.items():
    os.mkdir(k)
    os.chdir(k)
    path = os.getcwd()
    ch_r = requests.get(v)
    new_r = BeautifulSoup(ch_r.text) 
    chapter_titles_and_links = {}
    chapter_titles_and_links = { link.find('a').get_text().strip('\"'): link.find('a').get('href') for link in new_r.find('article', class_="markdown-body").find('ul').find_all('li')}
    for title,link in chapter_titles_and_links.items():
        p = subprocess.Popen(['touch', title])
        with open(os.path.join(path,title), 'w+') as chapter:
            ch_file = requests.get('https://github.com' + link)
            chapter.write(ch_file.text)

    os.chdir('..')
```

and this is the INITIAL exception that i got.

```
  new_r = BeautifulSoup(ch_r.text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ydkjs_scraper.py", line 56, in <module>
    chapter = open(os.path.join(path,title), 'r+')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/r2t2/Documents/it docs/youdontknowjsvenv/Up & Going/Foreword'
```

Maybe someone can try to run this script in their own virtual environment to reproduce the exception. Thanks.

EDIT:
after editing to use file context manager instead, suggested by Alexander Cecile, I was able to get the script running for the first book/directory with its chapters but then the script timed out and now throws this exception below

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.comhttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //shanehudson.net/2014/06/03/foreword-dont-know-js/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc41117eef0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

I will edit once i make changes to use session.get() instead as suggested by someone in another thread.

Comment: Always use [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) to handle files, they’re incredibly helpful! It also looks like you open and close the same file for every loop iteration. I’ll produce a refactored version ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I used a context manager instead but still ran into the same issue. Then I changed the mode for the file handling from 'r+' to 'w+' and that got things going. The script worked for the first book but the the script timed out and got a timed out exception with requests. My guess is GitHub is trying to limit or prevent long running scraping on their site. I just came across another thread that mentioned using session.get() instead, so will try that. Good looking out again for your answer, much appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the changes?

Comment: I'm happy that you've found a solution, but please don't fix your code and switch the topic. Instead answer this question (yes, you can answer your own question), and ask a new question about the new error. See [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/4518341) under "Editing Code in Questions", also [mre] and [ask]. (I deleted my previous comment cause it was unclear.)

Comment: @wjandrea you’re right, I should have read OP’s comment more closely, it’s definitely a different topic/issue.